# Como guardar un valor en mysql con express

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, express

estoy haciendo un login pero tengo un problema que no puedo guardar los datos en mysql. Para el register hice un form con un method post. Con express cree la conexion que es esta:

```
const mysql= require("mysql");

module.exports=()=>{
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host:"localhost",
        user:"pedri",
        password:"cocoypaco2",
        port:3306,
        database:"users"    
    });
};
```

Esta es la ruta del formulario:

```
routes.post("/register/newuser",(req,res)=>{
    controller.register
});
```

E hice una carpeta aparte para poner los modificadores de datos de mysql. En este caso llamado controller.

El controller.register es esto:

```
const controller= {};
const mysql= require("../mysql/mysql");

controller.register=(req,res)=>{
    var inputname= req.body.inputname;
    var inputsurname= req.body.inputsurname;
    var inputemail= req.body.inputemail;
    var inputpassword = req.body.inputpassword;

    mysql.connection((req, res)=>{
        connection.query("INSERT INTO user (name, surname, password, email)
        VALUES (inputname, inputsurname, inputpassword, inputemailf)");
    })
};

module.exports=controller;
```

Alguien sabe de casualidad que estoy haciendo mal? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```js
mysql.connection( // 1
    (req, res)=>{ // 2
        connection.query("INSERT INTO user (name, surname, password, email)
        VALUES (inputname, inputsurname, inputpassword, inputemailf)"); // 3
})
```

1. Ya estás exportando una conexión desde el archivo `connection.js`, solo debería usarla en tu controlador y no tratar de crear otra.
2. La función callback que recibe los parámetros request y response se utiliza como manejador de una petición a una ruta de Express, ese código no tiene sentido.
3. Los argumentos que estás pasando al insert son cadenas de caracteres, y deberían ser referencias a las variables que definiste justo arriba.

Una forma de hacerlo es:

```js
connection.query(
    "INSERT INTO user (name, surname, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
    [inputname, inputsurname, inputpassword, inputemailf],
    function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) { /* haz algo */ }
        if (results) { /* haz otra cosa */ }
    }
)
```

[Documentación](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries)